# Diagnosing boot performance on Win7

Tags: windows-7, boot, performance

I am trying to diagnose the problems I've been having with boot-up on my machine.
The system drive is an SSD, so it should be fairly quick.
However there is one moment, right after the "Welcome" wheel where I get the mouse and a black screen for a very long time.

Now you can find the boot logs here:
95.42.32.75/z (BootCKCL.etl file, opens with windows performance toolkit)

I did several boot-ups and the results are always the same.
In this particular one at about the 0:36 sec mark you'll notice this wide gap where nothing happens for about a minute.

It also doesn't seem to be related to any of the processes prior to the gap(tried to disable those).
I have no idea what the bottleneck is and don't even know where to start.

P.S. I also tried the suggestion from one of the other threads here. There was a suggestion to run

```
xperf -start perf!GeneralProfiles.InBuffer && timeout -1 && xperf -stop perf!GeneralProfiles.InBuffer myTrace.etl
```

But that gave me an error message:

```
xperf: error: Failed to start profile: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (0x800700b7).
```

Which I couldn't figure out how to fix.

Comment: So you gain no performance increase if you disabled ALL startup applications?

Comment: I disabled the last three there. There's lots of them.  Its unfeasible to try to disable all of those. The  problem is how do I narrow it down and how do I find out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: So, does a file with the name of `myTrace.etl` already exist, as the error message indicates?

Comment: I created a new post you might find helpful http://superuser.com/questions/594625/how-can-i-analyze-performance-issues-before-during-the-logon-process I'm still working on it though

Comment: follow my guide here: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140247 to capture a boot trace. Also install the updates/hotfixes from here: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=152622 and run the optimization if you use a HDD: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140262

Comment: the errormessage 0x800700b7 shows up if you already run a tool which uses ETW (ProcessExplorer for example). But xperf is the wrong tool. Use xbootmgr.

Comment: Yes, I guess running PE on startup was the culprit. It runs more or less permanently on my system.  As for the traces - the I'm not sure what to make of them. The xbootmgr bit produces roughly the same result as the default boot trace windows seems to do automaitcally. The ProcMon bit seemed a bit more promising( http://imgur.com/TXlOeaj ) but I'm not sure what to do about that one either.

Comment: upload the xbootmgr generated ETL file.

Comment: 95.42.32.75/z/BootTrace_Manual.rar  Should be up most of the time.

Comment: the link doesn't work. Please also use the @ before my name so that i get notified if you reply.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry about that. I hope you're comfortable downloading from my machine directly. And unfortunate that you tried it in the 2 hours it was off.

Comment: ok, I got the file now and reply in an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your boot is slow because of a long **WinLogonInit** phase:

[image]

When looking into the Generic Events of the WinLogonInit phase I saw that reconnecting the network drives takes most time:

[image]

So disable the network drives and reconnect them via

```
net use <driveletter>: \\Server\Share /persistent:no
```

on demand when you really need the network drives.

Comment: WOW...  That actually worked brilliantly! Thank you so much.  And at the same time somehow I'm not surprised that this exactly is the culprit.

Comment: You're welcome. enjoy your fast booting Win7.