# Program in startup folder doesn't run on startup

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I used Autohotkey to compile an Autohotkey script and placed the compiled program in the Windows startup folder. When I start Windows, however, the program no longer runs (it used to). I also tried placing the program somewhere else and putting a shortcut to it in the startup folder.

How can I figure out what's happening and fix it?

Comment: Does it still run if you start it manually?  Have you tried recompiling it into a new EXE?

Comment: @techie007, It still runs when I run it manually, I haven't tried recompiling. sfc says it found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.

Comment: Have you done a disk check recently?

Comment: @techie007, I did run sfc, but it said it found corrupt files it couldn't repair.

Comment: Does your program require admin rights (-> UAC)? Does your program require network drives that are not mapped any more? Are there other programs in the startup folder and are they run successfully?

Answer (score 9):

You Must be aware that some program needs Administrative privilege to start. Keeping program simply in startup folder doesn't provide the program permission to execute it.

1. You either need to remove the Option to run program as administrator.

   - To do this, right click and go to property of the program and in Advance button of shortcut, uncheck the Run As Administrator.
   - But this may leads to app not work properly for the task it need administrator privilege.
2. Another option is to create a scheduled task.

   - Open scheduled task and select the program in new task and execute it on every startup.
   - Since Configuring Scheduled task needs admin privilege already, so your program will be already granted admin permission.

So it will work!

Comment: How may be *disabling* of _Run as Administrator_ harmful to anything? The opposite action (enabling it) may be harmful for sure. Disabling it may only cause an app to stop working or behave differently. In fact, you're just decreasing rights an app have, so I cannot imagine how it may be harmful for security...

Comment: Yes, my mistake, i have corrected it. :-) thank you

Comment: actually UNCHECKING ru as admin fixed this problem for me

Comment: but why does having a shortcut with "Run As Administrator" making it unable to autostart?

Answer (score 1):

You could try referencing it directly in the registry key HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Run [ProcessMonitor and capture a bootlog](https://superuser.com/a/594626/174557). Open it and look in the processTree if the exe was ever started and if yes, how long did it run. You can go to the Events and look for details in the Result column.

Watch this video from Mark at TechEd 2013:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WCA-B306

Answer (score 0):

I've looked up this issue on lots of websites in the last three days.  none of them resolved the issue.  Once I lowered the user account control settings, The shortcut then started up properly running as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The program doesn't start automatically because it needs your permission to launch. Change "user account control" to "never notify" and your program will start automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Dheeraj's answer with a third option:

3 dont run AutoHotkey.exe as admin but only the script that needs it.

- Instead of running `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe` as admin (by checking the box `run as admin` in righ click/property), simply add this code somewhere at the top of your script that need to run as admin:

```
; run script as admin (reload if not as admin)
if not A_IsAdmin
{
   Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Requires v1.0.92.01+
   ExitApp
}
```