# Windows 10 is very slow to login

Tags: windows-10, login

Currently, my Windows 10 install (Pro edition, build 10586.29) is experiencing a problem with extremely slow logins (up to three minutes on the "black screen of death" -- cursor is visible, but absolutely nothing actually happens) after entering my login password. Additionally, the Windows Shell can take upwards of five minutes to load (items to display on my taskbar, shortcut icons to load, etc).

I've attempted to attach a debugger (through `procmon`) to my boot process, but I have yet been unable to find anything out of the ordinary, with the exception of about a three minute gap between two registry lookups:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1MDPvrb.png]

All of this happens before `atbroker` and `UserInit` start (I think).

During this gap, many processes (Specifically NVIDIA and ELAN) launch, but none seem to contribute to a hang.

I have no idea about how to debug this, what's causing it, and (most importantly), how to fix it. Can someone please help me out?

---

Winlogon's process tree:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/LboMBll.png]

---

**Edit:** I've noticed that this only happens when I first boot my computer. Any subsequent logons/logoffs work perfectly normally.

**Edit 2:** Upon doing a bit of log debugging, I noticed something in my boot logs:

```
This application took longer than usual to start up, resulting in a performance degradation in the system startup process: 
     File Name          :   MsMpEng.exe
     Friendly Name      :   Antimalware Service Executable
     Version            :   4.9.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)
     Total Time         :   48205ms
     Degradation Time   :   45705ms
     Incident Time (UTC):   ‎2015‎-‎12‎-‎13T05:50:13.777810900Z
```

This suggests something is wrong with Windows Defender (again). Now what?

**Edit 3:** Also, I'm using Razer Synapse because of my keyboard and mouse, and [quite a few different people](https://www.reddit.com/r/Games/comments/21a3ah/xpost_rrazer_razer_synapse_20_increases_my_boot/) confirm that it actually does slow boot. Can that be remedied somehow (preferably without uninstalling Synapse)?

Comment: Have you run Windows Performance Toolkit's boot profiler?

Comment: @oldmud0 Is there any guide for using the boot profiler?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/594625/how-can-i-analyze-performance-issues-before-during-the-logon-process

Answer (score 6):

You should use [xperf to troubleshoot slow logons](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10128.tools-for-troubleshooting-slow-boots-and-slow-logons-sbsl.aspx#Using_XPERF_to_capture_slow_logons).

1. install the [WPT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx)
2. logon to an admin account
3. open a cmd.exe and run this command:

> xperf -on base+latency+dispatcher+NetworkTrace+Registry+FileIO
>   -stackWalk CSwitch+ReadyThread+ThreadCreate+Profile -BufferSize 1024 -start UserTrace -on "Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Core+Microsoft-Windows-Wininit+Microsoft-Windows-Folder Redirection+Microsoft-Windows-User Profiles
>   Service+Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy+Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon+Microsoft-Windows-Security-Kerberos+Microsoft-Windows-User
>   Profiles
>   General+e5ba83f6-07d0-46b1-8bc7-7e669a1d31dc+63b530f8-29c9-4880-a5b4-b8179096e7b8+2f07e2ee-15db-40f1-90ef-9d7ba282188a"
>   -BufferSize 1024 -MinBuffers 64 -MaxBuffers 128 -MaxFile 1024

4. Press CTRL+ALT+DEL and then Switch User.
5. Logon with the user account experiencing the slow user logon to reproduce the issue.
6. in the slow account, open a elevated/admin command prompt and run this:

> xperf -stop -stop UserTrace -d merged.etl

7. open the `merged.etl` in [WPA.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448170.aspx), look in the Generic Events for events with matching Start/Stop Opcodes and look which Event has a long duration.

If you need help, compress the `merged.etl` as 7z/RAR (to reduce the size) and share it (oneDrive, dropbox, google drive).

Comment: Windows Performance Toolkit is now part of Windows Assessment and Deployment Toolkit.  The Download is here, you can uncheck everything else that you don't need:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install

Comment: @JasonStevenson the WPT was part of ADK since Windows 8, but I prefer the SDK to also get Debuggin tools

Comment: It didn't reveal anything obvious but I noticed a few instances of HuionTablet.exe running.  Uninstalled that driver and voila, opening the login screen lightning fast again between users LOL.